# R: save_plot: how to remove the space in the bottom of figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I used the save_plot function in the 'cowplot' package for multiple plots. However, I am not able to remove the big space in the bottom of the figures. Please anyone could advise how to do? Thanks

```
  library(ggthemes) 
  library(cowplot)
  theme_set(theme_gray()) 
  rft <- gpdRangeFit(DatMaxSub$DatMax,umin=2,umax=4)
  p1<-ggplot(rft)
  m <- mrl(DatMaxSub$DatMax)
  p2<- ggplot(m)
  p12 <- plot_grid(p1[[1]],p1[[2]], p2, labels = NULL,nrows=3,ncol=1,align = 'v',
                   axis="b",scale=1)
  save_plot(paste('04_Thres_',parname,'.png'), p12,nrow = 3,ncol=1,base_height=3, 
            base_aspect_ratio = 2) # make room for figure legend
  dev.off()
```

[The example figure with lots of space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw4CA.png)